# Coffeescript converts try / catch / finally block oddly when a function reference is used

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, promise

I have a helper function for dealing with errors. I'm trying to pass this as a parameter to the `catch` function in a promise:

```
  fetchRecords().then (found) ->
    $scope.recprds = found;
  .catch( Session.handleError )
  .finally( -> $scope.querying = false )
```

This gets parsed into the following Javascript:

```
  fetchRecords().then(function(found) {
    return $scope.records = found;
  })["catch"](Session.handleError)["finally"](function() {
    return $scope.querying = false;
  });
```

Which cases a JavaScript error because `finally` is not a property of my `Session.handleError` function.

Is there a different syntax I should be using?

[Try it out on coffeescript.org](http://coffeescript.org/#try:%20%20fetchRecords().then%20(found)%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%24scope.recprds%20%3D%20found%3B%0A%20%20.catch(%20Session.handleError%20)%0A%20%20.finally(%20-%3E%20%24scope.querying%20%3D%20false%20)%0A)

Comment: Putting extra parentheses around everything but the .finally works, but is ugly.

Comment: `finally` is not accessed as a property of `Session.handleError` in the code you posted? What error are you getting?

Comment: @Bergi, I was getting that error, but now I cannot reproduce it. Original code works correctly. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: you should delete the ; and the ( ) where they are not needed.

The words try catch and finally are reserved words. You should use them like the example at the coffeescript.org page:

```
try
  allHellBreaksLoose()
  catsAndDogsLivingTogether()
catch error
  print error
finally
  cleanUp()
```

If you change your function names the chaining in coffeescript is working. So you should rename your helper functions and the chaining should work.

```
  fetchRecords().then (found) ->
    $scope.recprds = found
  .helpercatch Session.handleError 
  .helperfinally -> $scope.querying = false
```

Parses:

```
fetchRecords().then(function(found) {
  return $scope.recprds = found;
}).helpercatch(Session.handleError).helperfinally(function() {
  return $scope.querying = false;
});
```

Comment: Renaming helpers is not an option in this case, as it's part of the angular $q promise API.